# Audio "Buzz" noise from headphone jack into external speakers

Tags: pulseaudio

ASUS N550JV laptop dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1.
I have an external speaker plugged in all the time since I usually use my laptop as a desktop. The problem occurs when the laptop is not plugged into a power source. After a few seconds of not receiving any sort of audio signal the headphone jack power is turned off and I get a very loud Hum or buzz from the speakers. This is probably a power saving feature. Does anyone know where I can tweak my system to leave the headphone jack power on?

Also on a side note I'm not able to send audio through the hdmi outlet currently. I'm using Xorg and my card is Nvidia GT 750M and its the hybrid graphics I believe. So depending on usage it might be using the Intel HD 4600 instead of the Nvidia.

Comment: Does it happens with Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You try to uninstall Realtek Audio Driver and install new audio driver v.6017083. Please download and install the latest driver update from below link.

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin8/Audio/Audio_Realtek_Win8_64_VER6017083.zip

I hope I can fix it for you.